# Integrating react into EJS project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, web, ejs

I'm trying to integrate React (and subsequentially JSX) into my already built / established project that uses EJS. (EJS w/ Node, express, mongo, browserify).

Basically I need to build a partial in React and put it into my ejs project (if I'm using the correct terms!)

Does anyone have any pointers on how to do this? I have done a lot of research but no luck with how to actually execute this integration.

Comment: also interested in this one, did you manage it?

Comment: No i didint. ended up finding a js package that did what i needed so I gave up...

Comment: I literally have exactly the same stack and I was looking around for the same sort of answers without using SSR! Let me know if you had any luck...